# How to put Auth Allow in ruby like CakePHP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, cakephp

I have a `users_controller.rb`. There are too many method including `login`, `register`, `forgot_password` and `logout` I want to put auth allow these actions in my ruby controller.

I have done `$this->Auth->allow` in the CakePHP.

```
$this->Auth->allow('register', 'login', 'forgot_password', 'logout');
```

But in the ruby this is very hard to put. Please suggest me -

```
def login
    @title = 'Login'
    #render layout: 'login'
end
def dashboard
    if logged_in?
      @title = 'My Dashboard'
      @user = User.get_profile(session[:user_id])
      @user = User.get_profile(session[:user_id])
      #raise @myProfile.inspect
    else
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
end
def my_profile
  if logged_in?
    @title = 'My Profile'
    @user = User.get_profile(session[:user_id])
  else
     redirect_to '/login'
  end
end

def logout
    log_out
    redirect_to '/login'
end
```

Each time I am adding `if logged_in? ... else ... end` in my every action. So
I want to put Auth Allow in ruby like CakePHP code. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've created your own authentication system, instead of using a gem, so if you want a method to check for a logged in user, you can add it.

In application_controller.rb

```
def authenticate_user
  redirect_to login_path unless logged_in?
end
```

Then in any controller you want to require a user to be signed in you can do

```
class YourController < ApplicationContoller
  before_action :authetnicate_user, except: [:actions_that_doesnt_need_auth]

  ... 
  # All normal methods
end
```

That being said - the previous answer about using RESTful resources is important to understand and keep in mind.  If you have questions you can ask :)

Comment: I am following your answer. Here is getting error message `undefined method `authetnicate_user' for #<UsersController:0x451ab08>`

Comment: Little bit coding error answer. By the way your code is write. You should be add `self.authenticate_user` instead of `authenticate_user` in the application controller. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Those actions should be in separate controllers, there are [plenty](http://www.sitepoint.com/restful-rails-part-i/) of [resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) available to explain this, search for "RESTful Rails".

Once they are in separate controllers you can use a "[before](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)" action to prevent unauthorised users from accessing those actions.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. :)

Comment: I got another problem. After login still `http://localhost:3000/login` page opening.